# Can't read data from existing table on hbase via phoenix

Tags: java, hbase, apache-phoenix

When using java querying Hbase via phoenix, I encounter a following problem:
My connection is ok, so I get all data from SYSTEM.CATALOG using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM SYSTEM.CATALOG
```

It give me result as:

```
TENANT_ID TABLE_SCHEM TABLE_NAME ...

null      DEVLOCAL    BASE_COMMENTS ...
null      SYSTEM      CATALOG ...
null      g           edges ...
null      g           messages ...
...
```

I guess that g.edge does exist so I try:

```
Select * from g.edges
```

And the problem starts here:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.phoenix.schema.TableNotFoundException: ERROR 1012 (42M03): Table undefined. tableName=G.EDGES
at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.getAllTableRegions(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:575)
at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.DefaultParallelScanGrouper.getRegionBoundaries(DefaultParallelScanGrouper.java:72)
at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.BaseResultIterators.getRegionBoundaries(BaseResultIterators.java:529)
at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.BaseResultIterators.getParallelScans(BaseResultIterators.java:696)
at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.BaseResultIterators.getParallelScans(BaseResultIterators.java:627)
at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.BaseResultIterators.<init>(BaseResultIterators.java:499)
at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.ParallelIterators.<init>(ParallelIterators.java:62)
at org.apache.phoenix.execute.ScanPlan.newIterator(ScanPlan.java:242)
at org.apache.phoenix.execute.BaseQueryPlan.iterator(BaseQueryPlan.java:351)
at org.apache.phoenix.execute.BaseQueryPlan.iterator(BaseQueryPlan.java:212)
at org.apache.phoenix.execute.BaseQueryPlan.iterator(BaseQueryPlan.java:207)
at org.apache.phoenix.execute.BaseQueryPlan.iterator(BaseQueryPlan.java:202)
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$1.call(PhoenixStatement.java:310)
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$1.call(PhoenixStatement.java:290)
at org.apache.phoenix.call.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:53)
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeQuery(PhoenixStatement.java:289)
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeQuery(PhoenixStatement.java:283)
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeQuery(PhoenixStatement.java:1706)
at HbaseDataProvider.query(HbaseDataProvider.java:29)
at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

... that G.EDGES is not exist. I tried "g"."edges" for not uppercase but still give me error like that
Please give me an idea or show me if I misunderstanding something.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked in hbase shell if your table is actually present in HBase?

Comment: Ofcourse, I created these tables using Hbase shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I fixed my problem. That caused by the lack of phoenix. Actually, apache phoenix is not auto-sync its metadata from hbase so if you have tables created using hbase shell, you first have to create tables with the same table name, schema name in phoenix so that phoenix can sync metadata from hbase. My fault is that I did not read the docs carefully.
Here is the reference: https://phoenix.apache.org/faq.html

Comment: `CREATE VIEW "table_name" (<list-of-columns>)` helped me